# What events can be added using addEventListener to WinJS.Promise?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, windows-store-apps, winjs

While exploring WinJS.Promise object, I noticed it has options to addEventListener to it. But I didn't find what kind of events that can be added to it ?

Everywhere I found

```
WinJS.Promise.addEventListener(type, listener, capture);
```

So I am looking for the hint/link/reference of events that can be added to WinJS.Promise object.

Thanks !!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211868.aspx you can find then in the docs

Comment: @Pedro, yes I have gone through the same. "error" is the event that can be added. What other events we can add? We also have onError, which can do same work as adding "error" event.

Comment: that's right you only have the error event in the promise objecthttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx#events

Comment: ahh..OK. Thanks @Pedro for pointing it. I somehow missed it. You can post the details as answer. So that I will accept the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the promise object only have the error event
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx#events